# Extraer value de una etiqueta div

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de obtener un valor de la siguiente manera

```
var pgr = $("#myProgress").val();
var mbar = $("#myBar").val();
```

Solo que me regresa vacio "", si hago con el

```
var prg = document.getElementById("myProgress");
```

Me regresa algo como lo siguiente = "`<div id="myBar" value="50" max="100" onclick="increase()"></div>`"

¿Hay alguna manera de a ese variable prg sacarle solo el value?

Todo esto es desde un archivo .js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente las etiquetas DIVs no deben llevar como propiedad "value" como tal, sino que se reserva para inputs, selects, elementos de formularios.

Lo que debes de hacer es poner un "data-value" como indica la documentación oficial de HTML5, osea:

```
<div data-value="valor"></div>
```

Entonces tomas este valor de la siguiente manera con JQuery:

```
var valor = $('div').attr('data-value');
```

Cualquier duda que tengas, puedes comentar.

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Para javascript puro es con [`.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text), quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
var prg = document.getElementById("myProgress").value;
```

---

Recuerda que el `.value` o `.val()` de jQuery son sólo para los `<input />` o `<textarea></textarea>`.

Comment: me lo pone como undefined, por eso lo estoy intentando hacer de la otra forma..

Comment: Podrías mostrar los elementos del DOM `myProgress` y `myBar`? Como para tener una mejor perspectiva de lo que te está sucediendo.

Answer (score 0):

Crea el div con la propiedad data-value

```
<div id="uno" class="caja" data-value="1">1</div>
```

luego en javaScript sacas el valor con  .dataset.value

```
let uno = document.getElementById('uno').dataset.value;
```

como se observa, el resultado que me daría a mi seria 1 por que ese valor le puse en la propiedad